# Receive Notifications in Android

Tags: android, push-notification, push

I want to intercept notification events in Android, my application receive notifications,

```
<service
    android:name="com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ETPushService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

But I want to maintain the salesforce register behaviour, and send personally notifications in android, by creating  NotificationCompat.Builder notification etc.

Is There a listen or something like else to use? Or I need to change this service to create my own service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override notification handling.  The [ANDROID LEARNING APP](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/LearningAppAndroid/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/salesforce/marketingcloud/android/demoapp/LearningAppApplication.java#L238) has 1 possible use-case example.  You could handle non-Salesforce notifications yourself and return a `null` builder to the SDK which will keep them from being displayed by the SDK.  You can also override any behavior and return a valid builder to the SDK -- this will allow the SDK to display the notification and accurately track the associated analytics.

Comment: Thank you, I used the same and created my own notification, very nice.